# Why is this structure being sent by parameter?

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I'm using a structure for my DES Algorithm:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    unsigned char *block;
}Blocks64;
```

I already did a lot of things to it, so i have some information on the unsigned char. I'm in a function that i call it iterations, and i need to send it by parameter, so i can modify it in the function and the changes stay on the structur, so to my knowledge, this is the way to do it:

```
void iterations(Block64 *blocks){
   printf("This is the first char: %c",get_64bBlocks_char(&blocks,0,0));
}
```

Inside the method, i have a `printf();` so i can check that is the same one as the one that i'm sending... and it is not. On the function where i call iterations, i have the same code:

```
printf("This is the first char: %c",get_64bBlocks_char(&blocks,0,0));
```

And it prints what i've stored in it, but inside the iterations method it isn't.

So just testing, i did this:

```
void iterations(Block64 blocks){
   printf("This is the first char: %c",get_64bBlocks_char(&blocks,0,0));
}
```

And now i'm receiving it correctly! And if i make a change inside the iterations method, it affects the one that is outside the method. I really don't understand! To my knowledge, i have to use a pointer to the structure so i can pass it by refference. My compiler right now is Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Turn on your warnings levels. One of the two shouldn't compile cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing the address of the pointer, which is not the address of the `struct`, just remove the `&` in the first version

```
void iterations(Block64 *blocks)
{
   printf("This is the first char: %c", get_64bBlocks_char(blocks, 0, 0));
}
```

since you are passing a pointer, then you don't need to take it's address to pass it back to `get_64bBlocks_char()`.

If you had compiler warnings turned on, then the compiler would tell you that the first parameter to `get_64bBlock_char()` is of incompatible type, since it would be `Block64 **` with the `&` operator.

The second case, is not going to work as you want it to, because the function would be working on a copy of the structure, hence, the changes made to it are not preserved after the function returns, because the copy is deallocated, and also because you need it to work on the original whose address has to be passed in order for it to be modified.

Comment: Ohhhh You're right! Thank you! But then also, why the other way it's working as well?

Comment: Because you are working on a copy of the structure, which is very likely **not what you want**.